# Can I suppress the level up popup menu during fights?

Tags: dota-2

Sometimes during a team fight I get a lvl up, and the interface wants me to learn some ability.

This is very frustrating as I'm trying to use some specific skill that may already be at top lvl, or it is a late game, and I can only learn stats. When u need to stun or escape, there is no time to learn a stat. Pretty often, I die in this situation or I lose precious seconds.

Is there any way to avoid this? Is there an option for learning skills to be background by default? (So you need to click on ability learn first, and then choose a skill)  Or is there any other way to accomplish this?

Comment: I'm pretty sure that you always need to pick the Upgrade Skill button before picking one. If you did get to be on normally though, you can definitely get it off somehow.

Answer (score 6):

Control+QWER to level up on the fly. It should never bother you again.

You should bind stats to a separate key. I use Z, so Control+Z levels stats for me.

Answer (score 3):

When you level up you are not forced to learn an ability and all your skills are usable. Its only if you press the "Level X" button (or "Point X" as I'm not familiar with the english HUD) that you can no longer use the key binded to a skill (skill being maxed or not).

In the settings of DotA 2 you can bind a key to "learn skill". In the battle and with a bit of training you should be able to press that key and then the key of the ability you want to level up (QWER or ASDF or whatever layout you use). You can bind a key to learn stat aswell so when all your skill are maxed up you just press the Key "Upgrade Skill" then the key "Learn Stats". You can also use this to quick learn your ultimate if you past 6 during a fight and use your ultimate immediatley to surprise the ennemy team (if you are quick enough). This should prevent any further frustration, will save you a lot of time and improve your focus on the game.